Leaving e-bike out in the rain WITHOUT battery
I ride an electric bike to work and I have to leave it outside. Sometimes I have to charge the battery which leaves the connector bit exposed. Apologies for my ignorance on the biking and electric terms. I mean the part the battery fits onto which is part of the electrics and looks like the prongs of a mains 13A plug. I know it's not ideal to leave the bike outside point blank. But as it's unavoidable I'm looking for advice on how to mitigate the harm caused. Particularly in regards to the electric components rather than the mechanical. I read that the internal wiring and electrics is all pretty safe and watertight its only the connectors to be wary of.I thought about making a little cover for the connector bit but didn't get much more sophisticated than tin foil and an elastic band. Here is a similar model of the bike I have for reference so you can see where the battery sits (below the seat post): https://ebikelist.co.uk/models/falcon-crest-20
Thanks in advance for your knowledge and experience:)
[![where the battery sits

If possible, could you add some additional pictures of the connections you are trying to protect? You can edit your question and add them to it. I think it would be really helpful in getting a well-informed and complete answer.

Are spare batteries available? Would you be worried about security leaving it outside with a battery fitted? Is covering the whole bike feasible (e.g. in terms of having somewhere to keep a wet cover when it's not on the bike?)

Can you talk nicely to someone and find a store room inside, where you can stash your bike out of the way?   No bike likes being outside a lot.

Aside - I'd definitely add a light layer of silicon grease on those contacts.  If they rust, your bike will have issues even if you put a cover on them.   Same goes for those upward-facing screw heads that will hold water.

You're thinking the right things, yes you want the battery terminal areas on the battery slider/receiver covered. Bosch has detachable covers that do the thing you're talking about, and people sell 3d printed ones for Shimano. Just making one is fine.

In truth the contact surface itself getting wet is not a huge concern, but this area on most ebike battery terminals will let water flow into areas you don't want it if uncovered. An underrated step in all of this is get a tube of silicon dielectric grease or penetrating anti-corrosion spray and keep a layer on the terminal area. Another great place to put it if possible is all the electrical contacts hiding inside the battery terminal area on the slider that water will flow into. It's very cheap insurance.

Very interesting answers to the question. Shapeways will often have 3-D printed bike parts and could be first destination for a search, at least in the US. Are there other sites people might recommend?

@WeiwenNg The Shimano ones above are from someone's Etsy.
